# How do I pass a variable to an action hook function?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, action, hook

I have a function that will initialize an image slider in my WordPress theme, however I can't get the PHP variables to be passed into it.  Here is the code:

```
function slideshowSettings ($pause_time) {
$code = "<script>
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('#camera_wrap_3').camera({
        height: '40%',
        thumbnails: true,
        time: ".$pause_time.",
        fx: '".$transition_effect."',
        transPeriod: ".$transition_speed.",
        autoAdvance: ".$auto_advance.",
        minHeight: '50px',
        mobileNavHover: false,
        imagePath: '".get_template_directory_uri()."/images/'
    });
});
</script>";

echo $code;
}
add_action('wp_head', 'slideshowSettings');
```

The variables are assigned above the function but the output I get from the function looks like this:

```
<script>
jQuery(function(){

    jQuery('#camera_wrap_3').camera({
        height: '40%',
        thumbnails: true,
        time: ,
        fx: '',
        transPeriod: ,
        autoAdvance: ,
        minHeight: '50px',
        mobileNavHover: false,
        imagePath: 'http://www.brainbuzzmedia.com/themes/simplybusiness/wp-content/themes/simplybusiness/images/'
    });
});
</script>
```

How can I pass those variables?

Comment: Offtopic: Your image path in the jQuery looks wrong `'http://www.brainbuzzmedia.com/themes/simplybusiness/wp-content/themes/simplybusiness/images/'`

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not.  Why does it look wrong?

Comment: unless your wordpress folder is situated in `'http://www.brainbuzzmedia.com/themes/simplybusiness/` then no problem :)

Answer (score 3):

You can't add arguments to the `wp_head` because none are passed to your hooked function when `do_action('wp_head');` is called by the `wp_head()` function. The arguments for `add_action()` are

1. The action to hook to, in your case "wp_head"
2. The function you want to execute, in your case "slideshowSettings"
3. The priority of execution, the default is 10
4. The number of arguments your function accepts (these have to be passed by `do_action` however)

If you need to be able to pass these values in outside of your hooked function to `wp_head`, I would use `apply_filters` to modify a value:

```
function slideshowSettings(){
    // set up defaults
    $settings = array('pause_time'=>10, 'other'=>999);
    $random_text = "foo";

    // apply filters
    $settings = apply_filters('slideshow_settings', $settings, $random_text);

    // set array key/values to variables
    extract( $settings );

    // will echo 1000 because value was updated by filter
    echo $pause_time;

    // will echo "foobar" because key was added/updated by filter
    echo $random_text; 

    // ... more code
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'slideshowSettings' );

function customSettings($settings, $random_text){
    // get your custom settings and update array
    $settings['pause_time'] = 1000;
    $settings['random_text'] = $random_text . "bar";
    return $settings;
}
// add function to filter, priority 10, 2 arguments ($settings array, $random_text string)
add_filter( 'slideshow_settings', 'customSettings', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: So how the heck do I implement that <script code after I call wp_head() if I can't pass variables to it in an action?

Comment: Where are your variables coming from? I just updated it to show how you can use a filter to modify values in the function hooked to wp_head - you could just look those values up in the function itself instead of passing them too.

Comment: I have a custom options panel in the wordpress admin area.  Use picks pause time, transition type, etc. saves it.  Those settings are passed as php variables.  All I want to do is put them in the jquery init code.  This works fine if I don't try to hook the init code into wp_head and just hard code it where I want it but I can't do it that way.

Comment: If they are saved in an options panel, you should load them with `get_option('option_name', $default)` in your hooked function, not pass them as arguments.

Comment: I essentially did that in the code above.  I defined neater variables by basically doing $pause_time = get_option('pause_time'); above and then echoed $pause_time in the hooked function, but it doesn't pass.  That's the problem.

Comment: You don't want to pass the variable to the function, you want to *create* the variable *in* the function. So instead of `$pause_time` being an argument to your `slideshowSettings()` function, add `$pause_time = get_option('pause_time');` inside it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19254/discussion-between-brainbuzz-media-and-doublesharp)

Comment: The problem is that when I define these inside the function they do not work.  I am not using get_option but rather a different method because these settings are set on the specific page you edit and are not sitewide. This is so there can be different sliders on different pages with different settings.

Comment: Then you should use `get_postmeta()` if it is a page specific value.

Comment: It doesn't use basic get_post_meta(), its a more complicated ajax field that is passed as this: $page_layout = json_decode(SmartMetaBox::get('content-layout')); and then filtered with a foreach with this: foreach($page_layout as $page_block) { and then assigned like this: $pause_time = $page_block->pause_time;

Answer (score 3):

The correct way of passing PHP variables to Javascript is using [`wp_localize_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script).

Check this [article by Otto](http://ottopress.com/2010/passing-parameters-from-php-to-javascripts-in-plugins/). And this [Q&A at WordPress StackExghange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/46809/12615).

---

In your Question you don't show where those variables are coming from, hence they are printing... nothing.

I just made a test. This creates the options values in the database.

```
add_action( 'init', 'so_13282503_init' );

function so_13282503_init() 
{
    if( !get_option('pause_time') )
    {
        update_option('pause_time', '50');
        update_option('transition_effect', 'elastic.easeIn');
        update_option('transition_speed', '400');
        update_option('auto_advance', '4');
    }
}
```

And this, an adapted version of your code:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'slideshowSettings' );

function slideshowSettings () 
{
    $pause_time = get_option('pause_time');
    $transition_effect = get_option('transition_effect');
    $transition_speed = get_option('transition_speed');
    $auto_advance = get_option('auto_advance');
    $code = "<script>
    jQuery(function(){
        jQuery('#camera_wrap_3').camera({
           height: '40%',
            thumbnails: true,
            time: ".$pause_time.",
            fx: '".$transition_effect."',
            transPeriod: ".$transition_speed.",
            autoAdvance: ".$auto_advance.",
            minHeight: '50px',
            mobileNavHover: false
        });
    });
</script>
";

    echo $code;
}
```

Which results in this being printed in the `<head>` of the site:

[image: result of code in the rendered html]

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the number of arguments after the priority argument in [add_action()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action)

```
 <?php add_action( $tag, $function_to_add, $priority, $accepted_args ); ?>
```

The wordpress codex has some examples about it.

You should note that your function is taking only on argument actually, and you're using undefined variables like  `$transition_effect`, `$transition_speed` and `$auto_advance` in that function.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I added the $pause_time argument just to see if it would do anything.  Do you think you could give me an example of how to use my function with the arguments / variables passed in the add_action?

Comment: This is not correct, the last argument is the *number* of arguments.

Comment: I unfortunately feel kind of lost with this.

Comment: @doublesharp yeah, I'm sorry. Number of arguments. then you send your arguments through a `do_action`.